# Make a system call to calculate a spreadsheet cell value

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible for me to make a system call in order to calculate a cell value in LibreOffice Calc?

To clarify, can I set a cell's formula to something like this:

```
=B3*C4-system("/my/amazing/script B3 C5")
```

where the contents of cells `B3` and `C5` would be sent to `/my/amazing/script` as arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't call external programs from inside a Calc formula directly, but you can define a **[User-defined function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions)** as a "wrapper". This function may use the **[`Shell` command](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Other_Functions_%28Runtime_Library%29)** to call an external program. This way, you can make a system call "indirectly".

Comment: This makes Calc immune to this [CSV exploit](http://georgemauer.net/2017/10/07/csv-injection.html)

Comment: I tried that on Linux but it didn't work. `Function VOL(a, b, c)
VOL = Shell("/usr/bin/gnome-calculator", 1, a+b+c, false)
End Function`, then `=VOL(1,2,3)` produced '0' and didn't run the calculator. Replacing 1 with 4 or `false` with `true` didn't help.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: Generally, it seems that the SHELL() command doesn't recognize STDOUT or the exit code of the executed command. To handle this, you may use the clipboard, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16336933/342546). Regarding your example: try `Shell("/usr/bin/gnome-calculator", 1, "-e " + a, false)`, with a as String = "1+2+3". This should open the calculator with the equation 1+2+3 ready to calculate.